# Setup application using EAR file in Oracle ADF

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf, oracle-adf-mobile

I have only EAR file of the application , how to use this file and setup an application in Jdeveloper.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,

Comment: is it Web App with JSP,JSPX Pages,task flow ...  or it contains only java classes?

Answer (score 2):

An EAR is an artifact and is used for deployment. It can't be used (AFAIK) to create a project in an IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Check https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/jdev/OJDUG/gs_dev_apps.htm#OJDUG419 
In the end it depends on what you try to archive. Without the source code you can't do much.